# WSL zsh Integrated VSCode User account change?

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hi not sure if this is possible or not to achieve, but I am looking to change the user account that is set when launching zsh terminal in VSCode from showing "Administrator" to "~" like it shows when you run VSCode with remote WSL and stand alone Ubuntu terminal.

Launching default VSCode:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVjMd.jpg)

Launching VSCode via Remote WSL extension:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRHus.jpg)

Comment: Embed the images rather than posting links, please.

Comment: I need 10 reputation points to add inline images.

Comment: Ah, I see. Apologies.